# How to generate client key & secret for application registering on my site & how to use OAuth to implement provider

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, oauth, oauth-2.0

Hi I have an rails application & I want to build an API for the same.I have never worked on API building so far. So please tell me from where should I start to build an API. I want to make it public so that developers can build application using my  API. I have two questions in my mind

1. [How should I generate & assign app key & app secret to an application](http://stakeventures.com/articles/2008/02/23/developing-oauth-clients-in-ruby)
2. [I know that for secure API access I have to use OAuth.](http://oauth.rubyforge.org/)
3. [I have read following links & tutorials but I am not getting it how to implement it.](http://www.railsatwork.com/2010/10/implementing-oauth-provider-part-1.html)

I tried to run demo at [here](https://github.com/albertyi) but only part is working but I am unable to run client part.

Please guide me in detail to learn this stuff. Thanks in advance...!

Comment: Could you clarify your needs? Do you want to build an OAuth provider API? What kind of API do you have in mind (security, scope, ...)?

Answer (score 3):

> It's been a while since this question was asked, and there are many great resources that have been created since, which I'll summarise and link to below.

#### Adding OAuth 2 provider functionality

The [Doorkeeper gem](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper) allows you to implement OAuth provider functionality, and is [well documented](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki) and well maintained. It integrates well [with Devise](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Running-Doorkeeper-with-Devise), and there are [example applications](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Example-Applications) to learn from.

On the client side of things (for testing the integration, or if you want to provide a Ruby client for external developers), you can use [OmniAuth](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth), and the Doorkeeper docs take you through the process of [creating a custom strategy](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Create-a-OmniAuth-strategy-for-your-provider).

#### You may not need OAuth?

Depending on what sort of API you're building, you may find that OAuth is overkill. OAuth is useful in cases where you are a content provider, and the *developer is a third party* that wants to access information *on behalf of a user*, but without needing knowledge of their password.

If your use case is more simple (e.g. you can provide a secret token and key directly to the API user), then generating and checking access tokens may be enough. In this case, you generate a key (using `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64`, or [`has_secure_token`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/secure_token.rb) if you're on Rails 5) and store it. The API user provides this token on each request in order to authenticate, and you can regenerate the token if the original is ever compromised.

More detailed info on that [here](https://www.codeschool.com/blog/2014/02/03/token-based-authentication-rails/) and [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api?view=asciicast).